# Add marginal effect t-statistics to an estout table

Tags: stata

I would like to add marginal effect t-statistics to an `estout` table (`ssc install estout`).

I can add marginal effect coefficients and standard errors with `estadd margins`.
However, `margins` does not add t-statistics.

I thought that I could add a t-statistic with `estadd matrix` but this code fails to calculate `margins_t`:

```
webuse grunfeld

eststo clear

regress mvalue c.kstock##c.invest
eststo

estadd margins, dydx(kstock)
estadd matrix margins_t = margins_b :/ margins_se
```

I want to report marginal effects for only `kstock` (i.e., only one of the interaction variables):

```
esttab, cells("b margins_b" "t(par) margins_se(par)")

--------------------------------------
                      (1)             
                   mvalue             
                      b/t margins_b/~e
--------------------------------------
kstock          -.0229636    -.2073908
              (-.0947377)   (.2213873)
invest           6.672997             
               (19.13787)             
c.kstock#c~t    -.0012636             
              (-4.351608)             
_cons            219.3425             
               (2.903506)             
--------------------------------------
N                     200             
--------------------------------------
```

The standard errors version works but I would prefer t-statistics.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following works for me:

```
webuse grunfeld

eststo clear

eststo m1: regress mvalue c.kstock##c.invest
eststo m2: margins, dydx(kstock) post

esttab m1 m2 using output, replace

type output.txt
--------------------------------------------
                      (1)             (2)   
                   mvalue                   
--------------------------------------------
kstock            -0.0230          -0.207   
                  (-0.09)         (-0.94)   

invest              6.673***                
                  (19.14)                   

c.kstock#c~t     -0.00126***                
                  (-4.35)                   

_cons               219.3**                 
                   (2.90)                   
--------------------------------------------
N                     200             200   
--------------------------------------------
t statistics in parentheses
* p<0.05, ** p<0.01, *** p<0.001
```

A revision addressing the concerns in OP's comment:

```
eststo clear

eststo m1: regress mvalue c.kstock##c.invest
estadd local Obs = e(N)

eststo m2: margins, dydx(kstock) post

esttab m1 m2, s(Obs) mtitles("(1)" "") nonumbers noobs


--------------------------------------------
                      (1)                   
--------------------------------------------
kstock            -0.0230          -0.207   
                  (-0.09)         (-0.94)   

invest              6.673***                
                  (19.14)                   

c.kstock#c~t     -0.00126***                
                  (-4.35)                   

_cons               219.3**                 
                   (2.90)                   
--------------------------------------------
Obs                   200                   
--------------------------------------------
t statistics in parentheses
* p<0.05, ** p<0.01, *** p<0.001
```

Comment: I may have to go this route. For me, the downside of this approach is that it generates another column number and footer entry. Also, combining the point estimates and marginal effects allows you to stack the results in one column.

Comment: Thanks. Manually modifying the appearance each time may be the most straightforward route.

Comment: `estout` is pretty flexible and can be extended with loops etc. But it does have a learning curve and you need to experiment.

Answer (score 0):

There are (at least) two problems with the code in my question.

1. `:/` is elementwise division in Mata. Use `matewd` for elementwise division in Stata. `matewd` is from a Stata technical bulletin, so use `findit matewd`.
2. Elementwise division would not retain column names, which `estout` uses to align coefficient estimates and other statistics properly.

The code below solves the original question but requires a handful of extra steps. It may be easier to manually modify the table layout than taking this handful of additional steps.

```
webuse grunfeld

eststo clear

regress mvalue c.kstock##c.invest
eststo

estadd margins, dydx(kstock)
matrix margins_b = e(margins_b)
matrix margins_se = e(margins_se)
matewd margins_b margins_se margins_t
local colnames : colnames margins_b
matrix colnames margins_t = "`colnames'"
estadd matrix margins_t


esttab, cells("b margins_b" "t(par) margins_t(par)")


// --------------------------------------
//                       (1)             
//                    mvalue             
//                       b/t margins_b/~t
// --------------------------------------
// kstock          -.0229636    -.2073908
//               (-.0947377)  (-.9367782)
// invest           6.672997             
//                (19.13787)             
// c.kstock#c~t    -.0012636             
//               (-4.351608)             
// _cons            219.3425             
//                (2.903506)             
// --------------------------------------
// N                     200             
// --------------------------------------


esttab, cells(b t(par) margins_b margins_t(par))


// -------------------------
//                       (1)
//                    mvalue
//              b/t/margin~t
// -------------------------
// kstock          -.0229636
//               (-.0947377)
//                 -.2073908
//               (-.9367782)
// invest           6.672997
//                (19.13787)


// c.kstock#c~t    -.0012636
//               (-4.351608)


// _cons            219.3425
//                (2.903506)


// -------------------------
// N                     200
// -------------------------
```